# SharePoint Online add-in test license creation error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I've been struggling with creating test license for a SharePoint add-in I'm developing. I have followed below documentations provided by Microsoft to create test license tokens.

[Add license checks to Office and SharePoint Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/add-license-checks-to-office-and-sharepoint-add-ins)

[Office and SharePoint Add-in license XML schema structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/add-in-license-schema)

For every token I've tried, I'm getting below error.

> Some license attributes are missing from the license token. 
>       Parameter name: rawXMLEntitlementToken

These are some of different variants of token (Token 1-4) I've tried which threw same error mentioned above.

Token 1:

```
<r v="0">
    <t aid="WA900006056" 
        pid="{E73E4711-181C-45D8-938E-E966C22FE761}" 
        oid="{8cf30d98-d6f9-4cde-8669-2d09749d8237}" 
        did="{42E3AD48-54AE-454D-A0EF-85F2908C68EF}" 
        ts="0" 
        et="Free" 
        sl="false" 
        ad="2018-12-18T17:30:41Z" 
        ed="2019-01-17T17:30:41Z" 
        sd="2018-12-18T17:30:41Z" 
        te="2018-12-20T17:30:41Z"
        test="true" 
        ss="1" />
    <d>VNNAnf36IrkyUVZlihQJNdUUZl/YFEfJOeldWBtd3IM=</d>
</r>
```

Token 2:

```
<r v="0">
    <t aid="WA900006056" 
        pid="{E73E4711-181C-45D8-938E-E966C22FE761}" 
        oid="{8cf30d98-d6f9-4cde-8669-2d09749d8237}" 
        did="{42E3AD48-54AE-454D-A0EF-85F2908C68EF}" 
        ts="1" 
        et="Trial" 
        sl="false" 
        ad="2018-12-18T17:30:41Z" 
        ed="2019-01-17T17:30:41Z" 
        sd="2018-12-18T17:30:41Z" 
        te="2018-12-20T17:30:41Z" 
        test="true" 
        ss="1" />
    <d>VNNAnf36IrkyUVZlihQJNdUUZl/YFEfJOeldWBtd3IM=</d>
</r>
```

Token 3:

```
<r v="0">
    <t aid="WA900006056" 
        pid="{E73E4711-181C-45D8-938E-E966C22FE761}" 
        oid="{8cf30d98-d6f9-4cde-8669-2d09749d8237}" 
        did="{42E3AD48-54AE-454D-A0EF-85F2908C68EF}" 
        ts="1" 
        et="Paid" 
        sl="false" 
        ad="2018-12-18T17:30:41Z" 
        ed="2019-01-17T17:30:41Z" 
        sd="2018-12-18T17:30:41Z" 
        te="2018-12-20T17:30:41Z" 
        test="true" 
        ss="0" />
    <d>VNNAnf36IrkyUVZlihQJNdUUZl/YFEfJOeldWBtd3IM=</d>
</r>
```

Token 4:

```
<r v="0">
    <t aid="WA900006056" 
        pid="{E73E4711-181C-45D8-938E-E966C22FE761}" 
        oid="{8cf30d98-d6f9-4cde-8669-2d09749d8237}" 
        did="{42E3AD48-54AE-454D-A0EF-85F2908C68EF}" 
        ts="1" 
        et="Paid" 
        sl="false" 
        ad="2018-12-18T17:30:41Z" 
        ed="2019-01-17T17:30:41Z" 
        sd="2018-12-18T17:30:41Z" 
        te="2018-12-20T17:30:41Z" 
        test="true" 
        ss="1" />
    <d>VNNAnf36IrkyUVZlihQJNdUUZl/YFEfJOeldWBtd3IM=</d>
</r>
```

### Observation 1

I've tried sending empty value for ***cid*** field as well (Token 5). When I send empty value for that, I get below error.

> EntitlementTokenPurchaserId field extracted from the given license token is null or empty.
>       Parameter name: rawXMLEntitlementToken

Token 5:

```
<r v="0">
    <t aid="WA900006056" 
        pid="{E73E4711-181C-45D8-938E-E966C22FE761}" 
        cid="" 
        oid="{8cf30d98-d6f9-4cde-8669-2d09749d8237}" 
        did="{42E3AD48-54AE-454D-A0EF-85F2908C68EF}" 
        ts="1" 
        et="Trial" 
        sl="false" 
        ad="2018-12-20T00:55:19Z" 
        ed="2019-01-19T00:55:19Z" 
        sd="2018-12-20T00:55:19Z" 
        te="2018-12-22T00:55:19Z" 
        test="true" 
        ss="1" />
    <d>VNNAnf36IrkyUVZlihQJNdUUZl/YFEfJOeldWBtd3IM=</d>
</r>
```

### Observation 2

I've tried below alterations to token and it didn't change above two exceptions thrown by the API.

1. Token with and without ***v="0"*** attribute in root node.
2. Token with deployment id as empty value (***did=""***)

### Observation 3

I have verified that user who send the token has admin privileges to the site collection which I try to apply license token to.

Any help to solve this issue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to resolve the error by adding value for ***cid***. Below is the token format finally worked for me.

```
<r v="0">
    <t aid="WA900006056" 
        pid="{E73E4711-181C-45D8-938E-E966C22FE761}" 
        cid="32F3E7FC559F4F49" 
        oid="{8cf30d98-d6f9-4cde-8669-2d09749d8237}" 
        did="{42E3AD48-54AE-454D-A0EF-85F2908C68EF}" 
        ts="1" 
        et="Trial" 
        sl="false" 
        ad="2018-12-20T00:55:19Z" 
        ed="2019-01-19T00:55:19Z" 
        sd="2018-12-20T00:55:19Z" 
        te="2018-12-22T00:55:19Z" 
        test="true" 
        ss="1" />
    <d>VNNAnf36IrkyUVZlihQJNdUUZl/YFEfJOeldWBtd3IM=</d>
</r>
```